# can someone explain what exactly is High : na in pine script

Tags: pine-script

Hi can somone please explain
this line of code

```
float ph = highestbars(high, prd) == 0 ? high : na
```

what exactly does `high : na` mean ? and its purpose

Answer (score 1):

It's a [ternary](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#op_%7Bquestion%7D%7Bcolon%7D) operator.
It's basically an `if-then-else` in a shorter format.
You can convert any [ternary](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#op_%7Bquestion%7D%7Bcolon%7D) (`?:`) construction to an `if-then-else` on [this website](https://converter.website-dev.eu/)

```
float ph = highestbars(high, prd) == 0 ? high : na
```

is equal to

```
float ph = na

if highestbars(high, prd) == 0
    ph := high
else
    ph := na
```